nestjs microservices mongodb atlas connectivity problem
I'm working on a NestJS microservices architecture and encountering issues connecting to MongoDB Atlas. The same MongoDB URI configuration works with a monolithic NestJS project, but it fails in my microservices setup, even with all IPs whitelisted in MongoDB Atlas.
I have tried a few solutions:

Verified that .env variables (like MongoDB URI) are loaded correctly in each service.

Tested with both a local MongoDB instance and MongoDB Atlas.

Confirmed that the MongoDB Atlas connection works in a single-project structure (monolith) but fails in the microservices setup.


Here’s how I’m setting up the MongooseModule for each service:
MongooseModule.forRoot(\`mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGODB_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD}@cluster.f4rts7w.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGODB_CROWDFUNDING_DATABASE}?retryWrites=true&w=majority\`)

Could the problem be related to differences in environment variable management or module loading in a microservices setup? Any suggestions or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Can you connect with other tools, e.g. mongo shell mongosh?
